# Moving terms & conditions checkbox to cart page - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've currently got a checkbox added to the checkout page for accepting the terms and conditions. I want to move this to the cart page, so they have to tick this to get through to the checkout page.

Here's my functions, is this possible?

```
add_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'add_checkout_tickbox', 9);

function add_checkout_tickbox() { ?>

<p class="form-row terms">
<input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" />
<label for="terms" class="checkbox">I accept I've seen the below terms</label>
<a href="/terms" class="btn-primary">See the terms</a>
</p>

<?php }

// Show notice if customer does not tick

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'not_approved');

function not_approved() {
    if ( ! $_POST['terms'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please acknowledge the terms and conditions' ), 'error' );
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't say this will work 100%, as I have not tried it myself but try ...

If you are not the Theme Developer, it is advisable to create a Child Theme first.  [Follow these steps, if needed >>>](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

You will then need to install the WordPress Plugin [Simply Show Hooks](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/simply-show-hooks/).  Once you have successfully installed said Plugin, you will be able to view all of the `Hooks` and `Actions` on your page by simply visiting each web page.

Next, go into your `functions.php` file, within your Child Theme if applicable, and enter: 
`remove_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'add_checkout_tickbox', 9);`

This will remove the checkbox.  If you are dealing with the `functions.php` file within the Parent theme, ensure that you place this entry **after** `add_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'add_checkout_tickbox', 9);`.  For both Parent and Child Theme entries, ensure the priority number of 9 is kept the same.

You then head to your Cart page and look for the relevant Hook, where you would like to place your Checkbox.  You should see the Hooks appear in Green boxes on your page.  Once you have found your Hook, you simply enter your attached coding, replacing `woocommerce_review_order_before_submit` with your desired Hook.  For example:

```
add_action('YOUR_DESIRED_HOOK', 'add_checkout_tickbox', 9);

function add_checkout_tickbox() { ?>

<p class="form-row terms">
<input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" />
<label for="terms" class="checkbox">I accept I've seen the below terms</label>
<a href="/terms" class="btn-primary">See the terms</a>
</p>

<?php }
```

After looking at your code, are you sure `{ ?>` and `<?php }` should be there?  This looks like an error but I could be wrong.  If this does not work, try removing `?>` and `<?php`

Once you are happy with your relocation, you can then uninstall/disable the Simply Show Hooks Plugin, until it is required again.

As I said, I have not done this myself so cannot say it will 100% work but do let us know how you get on.

Comment: I am desperately needing this function, would be nice to have some feedback from the question's author. I have tried but couldn't make it work...